# How to calculate logarithm in Java ME?

Tags: java, java-me

How can I calculate logarithm in Java ME? There isn't any method in Java ME's [`Math`](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr139/java/lang/Math.html) class for it, but it is [available](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29) in the Java SE's [`Math`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is suggested how it can be done [here](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?60817-Logarithms-in-J2Me).

Here's a solution from that site:

```
private static double pow(double base, int exp){
    if(exp == 0) return 1;
    double res = base;
    for(;exp > 1; --exp)
        res *= base;
    return res;
}

public static double log(double x) {
    long l = Double.doubleToLongBits(x);
    long exp = ((0x7ff0000000000000L & l) >> 52) - 1023;
    double man = (0x000fffffffffffffL & l) / (double)0x10000000000000L + 1.0;
    double lnm = 0.0;
    double a = (man - 1) / (man + 1);
    for( int n = 1; n < 7; n += 2) {
        lnm += pow(a, n) / n;
    }
    return 2 * lnm + exp * 0.69314718055994530941723212145818;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used Nikolay Klimchuk's "Float11" class for floating-point calculations in Java ME. The original link seems broken, but it's available [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-dalvik-vm-on-java/source/browse/trunk/dalvikvm_benchmark/src/henson/midp/Float11.java?r=22&spec=svn22).